# Cannot create new object instance with overriding __new__

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python's `__new__` in order to return something different than the actual object instance upon instantiating the class (whether that's clever or not is a different discussion). Below is a minimal example, in which I return a list of two class instances from `__new__`, instead of the actual class instance.

```python
from copy import deepcopy

class TestClass:

    def __new__(self, param=None):

        self.__init__(self, param=param)

        return [deepcopy(self), deepcopy(self)]

    def __init__(self, param=None):
        self.param = param


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TestClass(param=1)
    b = TestClass(param=2)
    print(a[0].param) #  prints 2!
```

However, it appears that I am not able to create actual object instances with this method, as can be seen in the minimal example. The `print` statement should print 1, but prints 2, meaning the parameters passed to the second invocation of `TestClass` overwrite the parameters of the first invocation. My guess is that `a` and `b` are references to the same *static* class TestClass, and my deepcopy isn't helping either, because it makes no sense for a static class.

How do I have to tweak `__new__` and `__init__` of `TestClass` such that I'm actually creating new instances (i.e. the print statement should print 1, not 2)?

(Python 3.5)

edit/small clarification: I actually do not want TestClass to be static (if that's the correct lingo anyway), but my non-functional implementation seems to produce something like a static class.

**Solution**

Thanks to Kay, the following code works:

```python
class TestClass(object):

    def __new__(cls, param):

        instance1 = object.__new__(cls)
        instance1.__init__(param)
        instance2 = object.__new__(cls)
        instance2.__init__(param)

        return instance1, instance2

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the first parameter to `__new__` `self`, but it is actually the class, commonly referred to as `cls`. So you are writing to the class, not the instances.

To actually get two instances use:

```
class X(object):
    def __new__(cls, param):
        self1 = object.__new__(cls)
        self1.__init__(param)
        self2 = object.__new__(cls)
        self2.__init__(param)
        return self1, self2
```

You cannot use deepcopy, since it will invoke `X.__new__()` (without the `param` parameter), which will cause a loop.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, OP acknowledged the questionable sense of the task. Of cause you should not do that in production. But if you only want to learn the meaning of `__new__`, then I guess the question is acceptable.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why not? OP wants `TestClass(1)` to give a tuple of two objects of type `TestClass` whose attribute `param` is equal to `1`. It's bizarre, and nothing I'd want to encounter in the wild, but it's a valid learning tool.

Comment: Great, thanks! And obviously the example doesn't make sense, it was really only a proxy to learn about `__new__`.

Answer (score 3):

The specific problem that causes `param` to be shared class-wide is highlighted if you use the right parameters for `__new__`. As @Kay mentions in his answer, `__new__` accepts a class as the first argument, not an instance.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls, param):
        cls.__init__(cls, param=param)
```

That's the error, because then it follows that `__init__` gets a class when it expects an instance.

```
def __init__(self, param):
    # remember that `self` here is `Foo`! so...
    self.param = param
    # ...means Foo.param = param, setting it class-wide!
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand!